# Maui issues publishing in windows release mode - project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for 'net6.0'

Tags: c#, maui, publish

I have been trying to publish a Maui application in windows.

I can successfully build in debug and releases mode.
I can publish in debug mode but when i try to publish in release mode it fails with the following errors:

```
1>Assets file 'XXXX\obj\project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for 'net6.0'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'net6.0' in the TargetFrameworks for your project.
1>Assets file 'XXXX\obj\project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for 'net6.0'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'net6.0' in the TargetFrameworks for your project.
1>Assets file 'XXXX\obj\project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for 'net6.0'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'net6.0' in the TargetFrameworks for your project.
1>Assets file 'XXXX\obj\project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for 'net6.0'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'net6.0' in the TargetFrameworks for your project.
1>Assets file 'XXXX\obj\project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for 'net6.0'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'net6.0' in the TargetFrameworks for your project.
========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish started at 14:51 and took 11,105 seconds ==========
========== Package: 0 succeeded, 1 failed ===========
```

Where the placeholder XXXX are the auxiliary projects that i have in the same solution referenced in the Maui project
Checking all the project files of those project i can see that they are targeting net.60:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

I have tryed following similar questions in stack which suggests:

Clearing the Bin obj folder

Cleaning the solution

Reloading all the projects

Running dotnet restore

Checking the Azure Service Authentication

But nothing fixed the issue.

Anyone had any similar issue and can lead me to the right path of resolution?

Comment: Try to manually remove `bin` and `obj` folders then run `dotnet publish` again.

Comment: How do you publish? From the UI or a command? If it's command, what is the command you're using?

Comment: Thank you for your replys , i have already tryed to clean the bin and obj folders. So far i have tryed to publish via the UI of visual studio 2022 , do you have some relevant parameters that i could use via the command line that could make a difference ?

Comment: For this, you can check document  [Publish a .NET MAUI app for Windows with the CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/windows/deployment/publish-cli) .